# How to differentiate $\frac{2x^5}{\tan x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{2x^5}{\tan x}$$

I can differentiate $2x^5$ ($10x^4$) and $\tan x$ ($\sec^2 x$) but can't do that one

Is there a rule I can apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three choices.

You can keep the function as a fraction, and use the [quotient rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuotientRule.html):
$$\frac{2x^5}{\tan x}$$

You can write the function as a product, and use the [product rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProductRule.html):
$$\frac{2x^5}{\tan x} \equiv 2x^5 \cdot \cot x$$

You can write the function as a product in a different way and use the product and [chain rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html)s:
$$\frac{2x^5}{\tan x} \equiv 2x^5 \cdot (\tan x)^{-1}$$

Comment: I would say infinitely many choices.

Comment: @Awesome Tell me just $100$ choices and I'll give you $1000\$$

Comment: You can write $x^5$ as $x^rx^{5-r}$. Now give me money...

Comment: @Awesome No, that's too unfair :p

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع That is too unfair... Give me my money. $NOW$

Comment: You at Paypal??

Comment: @Awesome You'll have to wait until my computer renders all the  $10^x$ possible ways that I can use to send you your money, and I only have an Intel Celeron so... (btw: $x\pm1\geqslant10^{\text{large number}}$)

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع You have to send your money only once. Why compute so many ways?

Comment: @Awesome Because I'm lazy, well more or less.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Where do you live?

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع India?

Comment: @Awesome Stretching from the coordinates: $+32,000,000$ and $-32,000,000$, in a small house made of more than $5!$ blocks, in the Minecraft world. More precisely, near one of the stars that make up the Milky way. ;-)

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع You have to specify the origin and your scale

Comment: @Awesome It's up to you to find it, even if it is difficult. :^p

Comment: Well Hakeem... one day I will come to take my money

Comment: How is $\cot x$ a "different way" from $(\tan x)^{-1}$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi the same way $-\csc^2 x$ is different from $-\sec^2x/\tan^2x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the quotient rule which is a little similar to the [chain rule](http://quantizd.blogspot.com/p/blog-page%5f7049.html), which says that: $$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)  =  \dfrac{g(x) f'(x)-f(x) g'(x)}{g(x)^2}.$$

In your example, let $f(x)=2x^5$, $f'(x)=10x^4$, $g(x)=\tan x$ and finally $g'(x)=\sec^2x$.

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as $2x^5\cot x$

You can use product rule : $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)g(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$

Answer (score 0):

How to differentiate $2x^5/\tan x$

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\dfrac uv\right) & = \dfrac{v\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} - u\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}}{v^2} \\
\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\dfrac{2x^5}{\tan x}\right)& = \tan x\cdot10x^4 - 2x^5\cdot(\sec x)^2)/(\tan x)^2 \\
             & =  \tan x\cdot10x^4-2x^5.(1+(\tan x)^2))/(\tan x)^2\\
             & = 10x^4/\tan x - 2x^5.\sec2x \\
             & = 10x^4*\cot x - 2x^5\sec2x \\
\end{align}$$